# Live log of commands run by a user

Tags: root

I need a live log of all the processes run by the root user, so that I can just tail the file or something, I know there is /root/.bash_history but that is not updated until the session has ended.

Is there a way I can set it up so that commands are written live to the end of a file?

Comment: it's called a keylogger

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347254/logging-terminal-commands-in-nix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For commands run when logged in as root, no.  However, if you require all users (and yourself) to execute with root privileges, via the sudo command, then yes.
Details:  http://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html.